# Azure HDInsight : what is head node in a hadoop cluster?

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I have just setup a Hadoop cluster in HDInsight and trying to get started with Hadoop. I have enabled remote login on the cluster and logged on to it. I have copied the data to be processed onto this box from my desktop. The documentation calls this box a head node and has an additional step which talks about copying the data to hadoop cluster. This confused me.

I have the following questions:

1. When I copied data from desktop to the box i logged on to, didnt it actually copy data to hadoop?
2. How is the first copy operation different from the second one?
3. What is a head node in Hadoop?

Comment: Just curious why you didn't mark the answer as the correct answer. Is something missing? I found the question and the answers quite informative.

Answer (score 7):

The head node in a HDInsight cluster is the machine runs a few of the services which make up the Hadoop platform, including the name node and the job tracker. Which broadly speaking control where data is, and where compute happens respectively.

To use HDInsight, you don't really need to log in to this head node and you don't *need* to use remote desktop to use it. I'd recommend using the powershell approach http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlnol/archive/2013/06/07/managing-your-hdinsight-cluster-with-powershell.aspx gives you a good guide to get that set up.

As far as copying data to the cluster, this is different to copying data to the head node (which is just one machine). When you setup a HDInsight cluster, you also link it to an Azure Storage account. You need to upload your data into the blobs storage account to make it accessible to the cluster. There are a number of good tools to help with this, I'd recommend [Azure Explorer](http://www.cerebrata.com/labs/azure-explorer) - disclosure: I work for the people who make it, but it is free :).

Comment: both name node and job tracker run on the same box? is this usual in a typical hadoop infrastructure? also, isn't it common to have multiple name nodes to avoid single point of failure? doesn't HDInsight accomodate for this?

Comment: You certainly can separate the name node and job tracker, and possibly should, depending on the scale of your cluster, but for reasonable sized things on HDInsight, it's fine. There can be a secondary name node which is a sort of warm spare, but in Hadoop version < 2 the name node is a single point of failure. In Hadoop 2 + there is some name node resilience, though this isn't really available in HDInsight at the moment (q4 2013).

Comment: Thanks. Very new to Hadoop, and trying to basically run a first run on Azure. Am reading about Hadoop, specifically Namenodes and Datanodes. Are these the same as Azure's Head Nodes and Worker Nodes, respectively?

(Addition: Off topic but if someone has any good docs for beginners I'd be super appreciative. No luck so far.)

Comment: The concept of jobtracker basically applies to 'old' hadoop (v1). Mostly these days everyone including HDInsight is running Hadoop 2. So there won't be jobtracker, but rather Resource Manager. This is part YARN, which plays role of resource management layer in Hadoop2. No jobtracker and tasktracker here. There are few more things in YARN apart from the Resource Manager which provide the functionality of resource management and scheduling.